# AS3 not supporting embedded font's very big size?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, fonts

I have embedded a font "Times New Roman" in my flash file. I am using this font in TextFormat. But when i assign very big size of the text like 150 or 200 the text is still small same like it was near 80 size. Following is the code:

```
// Embedded font with linkage "EngRegualar"
private var engRegular:Font = new EngRegular();
private var title_txt:TextField = new TextField();
private var title_txtFormat:TextFormat;

// In constructor:
title_txtFormat = new TextFormat(EngRegualar.fontName, 400, 0x000000);
title_txt.multiline = false;
title_txt.autoSize = "left";
title_txt.defaultTextFormat = title_txtFormat;
title_txt.text = "test"
addChild(title_txt);
```

I have also tried it with some other fonts like DroidSans, Arial, Century. All font stops increasing at some point. Please see the following screenshot, the above red text is dynamic text with above code and blue text is simple static text on stage with same 400 size of Times New Roman font family. [image: The above red text is dynamic text generated with above code and blue text is simple static text on stage with same 400 size of Times New Roman font family.]

Comment: You could try using a smaller size font, then increasing the scaleX and scaleY properties of the text container.  myText.scaleX = myText.scaleY = 2;  to double the text size

Comment: Ya, but is the bigger font size is not supported for dynamic font in as3?

Comment: It should be! but I don't see Adobe ever fixing any font embedding issues, even before flash died.